# How to use a SLD file from the QGIS console?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

How to apply a SLD file to a layer in QGIS from the QGIS console?

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
# selecting the layer
layer = iface.activeLayer()
# Apply SLD on the layer
layer.loadSldStyle("mystyle.sld")
```

It doesn't give a error. But I also don't get a result.

Comment: The code was indeed correct; I had to refresh the layer to see the changes.

Answer (score 2):

The code was correct; I had to refresh the layer:

```
layer.triggerRepaint()
```